# Facebook, домены приложения, обход ошибки

Tags: php, парсер, facebook-api

Пишу парсер, Facebook выдает ошибку:

> Невозможно загрузить URL: Домен этого URL не включен в список доменов приложения. Чтобы загрузить этот URL, добавьте все домены и поддомены своего приложения в поле «Домены приложения» в настройках вашего приложения.

Возможно ли это как-нибудь обойти?

Comment: https://m.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=1723462994580201 не похожая проблема? Вы код не добавили - трудно понять как у вас вызов происходит... Можете для сообщества код добавить?